# Python loop through api and append multiple objects as tuples to list

Tags: python, json, list, loops, tuples

I'm trying too loop through all pages of api and get multiples json objects and store these as tuples within the list and return the final list

This works fine with only 1 object but I can't get it to work once i start adding multiple. I've tried various tweaks and changing for to while loops but can't seem to get to work

```
def star_wars_characters(url):
    all_names1 = []
    response1 = requests.get(url)
    data1 = response1.json()

    for x in data1['results']:
        all_names1.append(x['name'])


    while data1['next'] is not None:
        response1 = requests.get(data1['next'])
        data1 = response1.json()

        for x in data1['results']:
            all_names1.append(x['name'])

    return all_names1


print(star_wars_characters("https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=1"))
```

I'm trying to achieve an output like below but for all pages. This is just results fro first page which I managed to return by changing for loops to while but couldn't get the remaining pages of data:

```
[('Luke Skywalker', '77'), ('C-3PO', '75'), ('R2-D2', '32'), ('Darth Vader', '136'), ('Leia Organa', '49'), ('Owen Lars', '120'), ('Beru Whitesun lars', '75'), ('R5-D4', '32'), ('Biggs Darklighter', '84'), ('Obi-Wan Kenobi', '77')]
```

Comment: do you get any erorr message? always put full error message (full Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Use `mylist.extend(another_list)` method to join two lists together

Comment: how do you use it with many pages ? Show it in question. You could create minimal working code so we could run it and see problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "all pages"? Isn't that what you're doing when you repeat it with `data1['next']`?

Comment: I tried your script, and it created a list with 87 characters. That's all the pages.

Comment: The script you posted isn't the same one that created the list you showed. It's just appending the name, not the name and mass. Post the correct script, maybe it's doing something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

def star_wars_characters(url):
    return_data = []

    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()

    while True:    
        for result in data['results']:
            return_data.append((result['name'], result['mass']))

        if data['next'] is None:
            break

        response = requests.get(data['next'])
        data = response.json()

    return return_data

print(star_wars_characters("https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=1"))
```